# Tomato yellowing on lower leaves with bumps

Tags: tomatoes

My big rainbow heirloom tomato is dislplaying yellowing on the bottom leaves with them drying out as well. I have 4 other kinds of tomato that are not displaying the same problems.

The tomatoes were transplanted 3 weeks ago and are growing nicely and a bit of yellowing won’t scare me but since I see little bumbs on the bottom I thought to get some help! So if anyone knows what this is and wants to help, I’d love to hear what you think!

[image]

Comment: I would isolate this plant from the rest ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the many fungal blights/diseases that tomatoes are prone to - exactly which one is harder to tell.

https://content.ces.ncsu.edu/early-blight-of-tomato

Removing the affected leaves and isolating the affected plant would be two steps for any of them, and reducing humidity / improving airflow (after removing affected leaves, so as not to help spread spores) as well as various anti-fungal treatments if the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

The bumps are probably edema, which is a common condition when starting indoors under lights. I don't see any evidence of blight personally, but maybe others are seeing something I'm not. The bumps should be proneo drying up later in certain conditioms, which is likely what happened to the dry parts of your current leaves. That could potentially be a mysterious disease or pest, but I doubt it.

Air circulation and proper temperates should help with edema and fertilizer should help with chlorosis (unless the chlorosis is caused by disease).

Don't get the leaves wet; that makes edema worse.

Comment: Thank you so much! I cut off the yellow leaves and the one with the bumps and I will repot them in larger containers and feed them! There is airflow and a normal house temperature about 20 degrees C. I I only water the ground not the plant itself. Is a neem oil green soap mixture helpful?

Comment: How bright are the lights that you're using?